# How do I change the culture from within Excel VBA

Tags: vba, culture

I have an excel workbook that uses VBA. This VBA works fine except when it is executed on a clients laptop configured with Japanese language settings. I know in VB.NET that I would need to flip the Culture to EN-US and then flip it back when I'm done with the VBA but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this solution to work in VBA. Is this possible? How so?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using just VBA: all the Application.Interrnational settings are read-only.
Usually the international problem is the other way round - VBA works in US-English.

What lines of code are giving you the problem in Japanese language settings?

Comment: It's the Monthname() function normally I throw it a number, such as 10, and it returns the text name of that month, ie "October" but on the Japanese configured machine it returns "10?"

Comment: If you want the Japanese month name try using format(10,"MMMM")  its supposed to work according to the Windows regional settings. If you want the English month name the simplest thing would to create your own array of Month-Names