# Force comma format, ignoring culture

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to format a `single` value to a string, in which the comma separator is a dot. However, since my computer runs with German language settings, I always get things like `1,23` instead of `1.23`. I tried

```
Format(factors(1) / 100, "##.##")
```

and

```
FormatNumber(factors(1) / 100, NumDigitsAfterDecimal:=2, GroupDigits:=vbFalse),
```

but with both I still get German formatting. How do I "override" this?

I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923648/how-do-i-change-the-culture-from-within-excel-vba); does that mean that I cannot change those settings at all?

I'm using Access 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You say to a string, so this may help. It is from a very long time ago, so ... :)

```
Dim IntPart, DecPart
''Format for this locale
cur = (Format(cur, "#,###.00"))
''This locale uses stop as decimal separator
''Change the "." to the decimal separator for your locale
If InStr(1, cur, ".") > 0 Then
    DecPart = Mid(cur, InStr(1, cur, ".") + 1)
Else
    DecPart = "00"
End If

''Ditto, change the stop.
IntPart = Mid(cur, 1, InStr(1, cur, ".") - 1)
''This locale uses comma for thousands separator, 
''so change the "," to the thousands separator for your locale
''and ="." to the required replacement separator
Do While InStr(1, IntPart, ",") > 0
    Mid(IntPart, InStr(1, IntPart, ","), 1) = "."
Loop
''This set the decimal separator to a comma,
''choose the separator required.
EUCurrency = IntPart & "," & DecPart
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought more about something more elegant (and concise) with a form like `FormatSpecial(num, "##.##", Culture:="de")`. But since that doesn't seem to exist, I'm going to use something like `Replace(Format(CStr(n), "##.##"), ",", ".")`. The numbers I'm dealing with all are small enough, so I don't need to care about the thousands separator. Still, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If your value is lesser or equal than 21,474,836.47 then you can do this short elegant way (I'm assuming that factor(1) is your single in an array):

```
factor(1) = Fix(factor(1)) & "." & Format(Abs(Fix(factor(1) * 100) Mod 100), "00")
```

Apparently, even though Microsoft states the contrary, you can't Mod a number outside the range of a Long value ((2 ^ 31) - 1), so if your number is greater than the Long range /100 you have to do it another way; see here: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=219244.
So if you might have values greater than 21 and so millons you have two options. One is doing it this in a similar fashion to Remou in his answer, looking for a point or a comma with InStr; the advantage is that the result will be always perfect, the disadvantage is that it's not clean and might take longer to run. The other way of doing it is as follows:

```
factor(1) = Fix(factor(1)) & "." & Format(Abs(Fix(factor(1) * 100) - (Fix(factor(1)) * 100)), "00)
```

The advantage is that it's clean (you might want to store fix(factor(1)) in a variable for speed reasons though), but it's not as accurate. For instance, if I give as parameter the value 214732133333,56999 with this last formula it returns 214732133333.56, which is my desired value (I'm not rounding numbers). But if I give as parameter the value 214732133333.569999 it returns 214732133333.57, which is not my desired value. Apparently in calculations with numbers bigger than long the rounding becomes buggy in Access.

Regarding the change of the local settings, I wouldn't do it, but I believe you can do it with SetLocaleInfo (google that if you want to see how to do it, you need to change the value of LOCALE_SDECIMAL). But it's risky, you might unadvertively leave the machine with the wrong configuration if you mess something up or if there's a problem and the execution of the routine stops. What you read in your link is about the locale settings for non-Unicode languages, which is a totally different animal altogether, and even when you do it manually you have to restart your computer.